# PHP Looping in an array to find how many elements can I sum without surpassing an amount

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to loop in a sorted descending array where if the value is bigger than 30 we unset the element and we increment a counter.

If the element is smaller than 30 we check the other element and see if the sum is bigger or smaller than 30.

If its smaller we add the following element, if it is bigger, we unset the element(s) used previously and increment the counter.

An example of the array would be [35, 20 ,15, 14, 9, 5]

```
for($x = 0; $x < $arrayItemSize; $x++)
    {
        if($sortArrayItem[$x] >= 30)
        {
            unset($weight[$x]);
            $counter++;
        }
        else if($sortArrayItem[$x] < 30)
        {
            for($i = $x++; $i < $arrayItemSize; $i++)
            {

                $newWeight = $sortArrayItem[$x] + $sortArrayItem[$i];
                if($newWeight >= 30)
                {
                    unset($weight[$x]);
                    unset($weight[$i]);
                    $counter++;
                }
                else {
                    unset($weight[$x]);
                    $x++;
                    $i++;
                    if($newWeight + $weight[$i] > 30)
                    {
                        unset($weight[$x]);
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is what i got so far, but i just get confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use `while` statement and 1 loop would be enough.

```
$source = array(35, 20 ,15, 14, 9, 5);
$i = 0 ;
$counter = 0;
$len = count($source);
while( $i < $len && $source[$i] > 14 ) {
    if($source[$i] >= 30 ) {
        unset($source[$i]);
        $counter++;
    } else if ($source[$i] < 30) {
        if($i + 1 < $len) {
            $sum = $source[$i] + $source[$i+1] ;
                unset($source[$i]);
                unset($source[$i + 1]);
                $i++;
                $counter += 2;
        }
    }
    $i++ ;
}

var_dump($source);
var_dump( $counter );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, i've came up with another solution to my problem, if you could just take a look and tell me your thought, it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i've come up with a different solution compared to @Nazeri. We check to see if the total weight is bigger or smaller than the amount specified. If bigger, we remove the biggest element from the total weight, unset it and increment the counter. If smaller we unset the whole array and increment the counter.

Feel free to leave any opinions or error found in the code.

```
if($arrayItemSize > 1)
{
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrayItemSize - 1; $x++)
    {
        if($itemTotalWeight <= 30)
        {
            unset($sortArrayItem);
            $counter++;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            $itemTotalWeight = $itemTotalWeight - $sortArrayItem[$x];
            unset($sortArrayItem[$x]);
            $counter++;

        }
    }

}
else {
            $counter++;

     }
```

Comment: How do you set the initial value for `itemTotalWeight` variable?

Comment: I think it will remove all elements of array

Comment: since the array is never fixed, we can add all elements with array_sum() when the array is created. Also i fixed the second if statement weight. Its back to the original value.

Comment: by calling `unset($sortArrayItem);` you remove `sortArrayItem` completely from memory. It doesn't work.

Comment: I think i did not explain the problem clearly or maybe it is wrong, but the goal of this was to see how many boxes, that could hold 30lbs, would we need to fit all elements in the array. So if the total of weight is below 30 from the start, it means we only need 1 box. However looking at it from another point , it seems that unset seems unnecessary to the problem since `$x` would increment and never go back if we would enter in the `else` statement. @EhsanNazeri

Comment: Now,I got your question.based on your explanation it's a good solution.